Is there a classification of connected sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$?
We know that in $\mathbb{R}$ with standard topology, a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is connected if and only if $A$ is an interval (including points, rays, $\mathbb{R}$).
Is there a classification of connected sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$?
